Is there a sequence $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ that satisfies these conditions?
Hi guys i came across an idea in some book, and i was wondering if there is a sequence $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ that meets these conditions:
$$1. \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x_i)^n \text{ converges.}$$
And also
$$2. \sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i \text{ converges.}$$
To the best of my knowledge this would mean, that $\left| 1-x_i \right| < 1$, which would mean, that $0 < x_i < 2$ so the inner sum would converge. Then the 1st condition could be reduced to this:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1-1+x_i} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x_i}$$
So basically i would need a sequence $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ that satisfies these convergence properties:
$$ 1. \sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i \text{ converges.}$$
$$ 2. \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x_i} \text{ converges.}$$
Is there such a sequence $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ or can it theoretically exist, or do these conditions contradict each other?

You need $x_n \to 0$ and $\frac 1 {x_n} \to 0$  which is impossible.

Yeah i was thinking the same, but since im really new to mathematics, i thought of asking if one can construct such a sequence with some technique unknown to me. Thanks!
